# LAN and Wi-Fi connections stop working in UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking

I have 2 computers connected to the same network ASUS with Windows 10 installed and DELL with UBUNTU.
Why I lost my Wi-Fi and LAN connections on DELL and everything works fine on ASUS.
UBUNTU sees my WiFi connection as "out of range".
Thanks.

Comment: There is no information to answer. "I have two cars. One does start, the other does not. Why?"

Comment: Some additional info: UBUNTU 14.04 LTS; Driver :b44, State: Unavailable; Default: no; Capabilities: Carrier Detect: yes; Wired Properties: Carrier Off.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.
The case:
Ubuntu listed **the name** of the logical connection, wireless network name, as out of range.
The resolution:
As the result of lose of wireless connection, I had to reset the router.
When I did it, it changes an assigned network name to the physical name assigned by manufacture.
As a router was configured long time ago that name **did not click the bell** and ubuntu message **out of range** happened to be were confusing.
Resolution:
Just reconfigured the router.
Ubuntu is an excellent OS and I appreciate time everybody spend reading my note.
Thanks.